# Sort the nested column order when narrowing

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have three section nested like this below.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
    A
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
            B
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
            C
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div>
```

in normal situation ,it shows

```
| A | B | C |
```

it is good.

but when browser gets narrows (like mobiles).

I want to show like this

```
|   |  B |
| A |----| 
|   |  C |
```

So I use this.

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
```

B C is stacked vertically as intended, however A area is taken by B&C.

```
||B|
|| | <-- A is under B&C
||C|
```

Is there any way to solve??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. You just have to add `col-sm-6` to the Column A and the wrapper for column B and C. See snippet below:

```css
@import 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css';

* {
color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-6"  style="background:blue">
    A
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12" style="background:red">
            B
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12"  style="background:green">
            C
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div>
</div>
```

PS: Test in full page view, and observe as you resize your browser

Comment: THank you vdry much. This is best explanation for me. I solved